# Android Alert title message cuts off after two lines

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use React Native's Alert for Android devices to display a message with a list of items, but the Alert Title for Android cuts off string after two lines with ellipses. Is there a way to display a longer title fully? I am not encountering this issue with iOS.